# Build a social timeline with 'in' query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore to build a social app modeled after Facebook. I see lots of posts that resemble Twitter with the followed/followers approach, but that doesn't feel like a great fit for an app that uses friends.

My data model would have a top-level collection ("posts") and each post would have the poster's user ID ("UserID"). To build the timeline, I'm thinking of simply using the new-ish 'in' query:

```
var timelineQuery = postsRef
    .where('UserID', whereIn: [user_123, user_456])
    .orderBy('timestamp');
```

'in' queries are limited to an array size of 10, but my app is pretty specialized, so my average user will likely only have a couple of friends even if I get 1M+ users. For my rare user that has 40 or 50 friends, I could run this query 4 or 5 times, with the more active friends in the first query and updating the timeline as subsequent results come in.

Is this a reasonable approach?  I don't see any examples using it, so am guessing I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, this sounds like a reasonable approach.

The common alternative is to invert the data model, by building an explicit "wall" for each user in the database. So in that scenario you'd find all a user's followers when they post, and then write the new post to the "wall" of each follower. This makes writing more complex and slower, but makes reads a lot simpler and *very* scalable.

Comment: Thanks @Frank! Yeah, I thought I'd code my proposed for the mvp and then consider "walls" in the future if need something more scalable in the future.